# Prove that $\det df(x)$ cannot vanish on an open set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f: R^2\to R^2$ be a $C^1$ map such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite for all $y\in R^2$. Prove that $\det df(x)$ cannot vanish on an open set.

My thoughts:
Suppose the determinant vanishes on an open set. Then it vanishes locally on every disc in the set. Any disc is convex, so $f$ is constant on that disc by the corollary to Rudin's Theorem 9.19 (Mean Value Theorem). So $f$ is locally constant. Let $D$ be one of the discs, $x\in D$. Then $f^{-1}(f(x))$ contains the entire disc $D$, a contradiction.

Is this argument valid?

Comment: If I understand you well, you claim that if $\det{df}$ vanishes on an open set then $f$ is constant on that set.  This is not true: take the projection on an axis.  A hint: you have never used the fact that the inverse image of any point is finite

Comment: Another hint:  *Rank*.

Comment: I can't validate your argument but I can propose an other idea:

Take $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $y=f(x)$.
For $x+\delta x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, there is $\delta y$ such that $y+\delta y = f(x+\delta x)$. We have :
$f(x+\delta x) = f(x) + \nabla_x f\cdot \delta x + o(\delta x)$
Hence $\delta y = \nabla_x f\cdot \delta x + o(\delta x)$.
If  $\det \nabla_x f$ vanishes, the  linear system  $\delta y = \nabla_x f\cdot \delta x$ has no solution or an infinite solutions which contradict the assumption on $f$. One problem of this solution is to take into account the remainder terms $o(\delta x)$ ...

Comment: @user539887 I see, I tried to use Rudin's clam that if $df=0$ on a convex open set, then $f$ is constant. But $\det df=0$ does not imply $df=0$. I think I did use the fact that the inverse image of any point is finite: I assumed that $df$ vanishes on an open set and found a point whose inverse image is infinite. But anyway this argument is invalid I guess.

Comment: If $\det{df}=0$ on some open connected set, then either the rank of $df$ is constantly equal to zero (then, by the [Constant rank theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem) the function is constant on some nbhd of any point), or there is a point where the rank is $1$.  But then the rank is $1$ on some nbhd of that point, and by that same theorem the preimage is locally the graph of a $C^1$ (scalar) function.

Comment: @user539887 Is it possible avoid using that theorem and use the inverse or implicit function theorem instead?..

Comment: The implicit function theorem, the inverse function theorem and the (constant) rank theorem are closely related to each other, see Krantz and Parks [The Implicit Function Theorem. History, Theory, and Applications](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461200598). But what's the use of looking for another when we have a (named!) theorem just tailored for our needs?