# Determinant does not vanish on an open subset.

Tags: determinant, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^1$ map such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a finite set for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that the determinant det $df(x)$ of the Jacobi matrix of $f$ cannot vanish on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Does the statement in the question hold?

What about the identity map? Doesn't the determinant vanish on $\phi$, an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877317/prove-that-det-dfx-cannot-vanish-on-an-open-set

Answer (score 0):

For the identity map the Jacobi matrix is the identity matrix, so it is not singular.

Comment: So, can't we say the determinant vanishes on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: This is your homework to prove. You looked for a counterexample. Unfortunately the indentity map fulfills both the hypothess and the statement of a theorem in question.

Comment: This example was included in the question, before this answer was given. Xplorer therefore wasn't looking for this counterexample, but more validation that this is a counterexample, or some other way to resolve this question.